# Issue with Sequential promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to understand promises properly.

I have a sleep function to which if I pass a time, it executes it with a delay. I want to execute everything in Sequence.

**Problem:**

1: 
**However, sometimes my done is getting called even before the promise is full filled. Can someone explain me where is the bug in my code?**

2: Can I use async await instead of promises here? if yes how?

**My attempt:**

```js
/* Do the following: 
2- creating sequential promise, by wait for 1s, 2s and 3s sequentially. And showing result for each promise is done.
3- creating parallel promise, by wait for 1s, 2s and 3s parallelly. And showing result when all promise is done.
4- creating mixed promise, by wait 1s, 2s squentially, after then wait for 3s, 4s, 5s parallelly.
5- createing sequential promise, by wait for 1s, undefined and 3s sequentially. catch the error.
6- createing sequential promise, by wait for 5 different numbers, with random number as input.
*/

// Sleep takes time and returns time+1 
const sleep = (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Resolving: ${time}+1`);
            resolve(time+1);
        }, time*1000);
    });
}


// Generate Random number within a range.
const randomNumber = (min=1, max=8) => { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min);
 } // -5~5
 

console.log(
sleep(randomNumber())
    .then(sleep(randomNumber()))
    .then(sleep(randomNumber()))
    .then(sleep(randomNumber()))
    .then(sleep(randomNumber()))
    .then((e)=> {
        console.log("Done", e); // Done called when all promises are done.
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.then` accepts a parameter which is a *function*, not a `Promise`. Change your

```
.then(sleep(randomNumber()))
```

s to

```
.then(() => sleep(randomNumber)
```

so that the *function* is put into the `Promise` chain, which will be called when the previous `.then` resolves. Otherwise, every `sleep(randomNumber())` will be called *immediately*, as soon as the Promise chain is created.

```js
/* Do the following: 
2- creating sequential promise, by wait for 1s, 2s and 3s sequentially. And showing result for each promise is done.
3- creating parallel promise, by wait for 1s, 2s and 3s parallelly. And showing result when all promise is done.
4- creating mixed promise, by wait 1s, 2s squentially, after then wait for 3s, 4s, 5s parallelly.
5- createing sequential promise, by wait for 1s, undefined and 3s sequentially. catch the error.
6- createing sequential promise, by wait for 5 different numbers, with random number as input.
*/

// Sleep takes time and returns time+1 
const sleep = (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Resolving: ${time}+1`);
            resolve(time+1);
        }, time*1000);
    });
}


// Generate Random number within a range.
const randomeNumber = (min=1, max=8) => { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min);
 } // -5~5
 

console.log(
sleep(randomeNumber())
    .then(() => sleep(randomeNumber()))
    .then(() => sleep(randomeNumber()))
    .then(() => sleep(randomeNumber()))
    .then(() => sleep(randomeNumber()))
    .then((e)=> {
        console.log("Done", e); // Done called when all promises are done.
    })
)
```

To run them in parallel and run something when they've all been resolved, use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([
  sleep(randomeNumber()),
  sleep(randomeNumber()),
  sleep(randomeNumber()),
  sleep(randomeNumber()),
  sleep(randomeNumber())
])
  .then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

Comment: Awesome!! THANK YOU! The first line explains it all. What if i want to run everything in Parallel?

Comment: See edit, use `Promise.all`